# Pandas groupby and calculated sum

Tags: python, r, pandas

currently iam translating some R Scripts to Python. But i am struggeling with the following line:

```
  return(trackTable[, .(
    AVERAGE_WIND_COMPONENT = sum(TRACK_WIND_COMPONENT*GROUND_DIST, na.rm = T)/sum(GROUND_DIST, na.rm = T) #PRÜFEN!!!!!
  ), by=KEY_COLUMN])
```

Now I tried to rewrite the R code in python:

```
table['temp'] = (table['track_wind_component'] * table['ground_dist']) / table['ground_dist']
AVERAGE_WIND_COMPONENT = table.groupby(['KEY_COLUMN'])['temp'].sum()
AVERAGE_WIND_COMPONENT = pd.DataFrame({'KEY_COLUMN':AVERAGE_WIND_COMPONENT.index, 'AVERAGE_WIND_COMPONENT':AVERAGE_WIND_COMPONENT.values})
```

But my results for the `AVERAGE_WIND_COMPONENT` are wrong...What did I translate wrong here? It is probably the groupby and as I build my temp column.

Example df:

```
    KEY_COLUMN  track_wind_component    ground_dist
0   xyz -0.000000   2.262407
1   xyz 0.000000    9.769840
2   xyz -135.378229 38.581616
3   xyz 11.971863   30.996997
4   xyz -78.208083  45.404430
5   xyz -88.718762  48.589553
6   xyz -118.302506 22.193426
7   xyz -71.033648  76.602917
8   xyz -68.369886  11.092901
9   xyz -65.706124  6.210328
10  xyz -60.822561  17.444752
11  xyz 39.630277   18.082869
12  xyz 102.477706  35.175366
13  xyz 43.061773   8.793499
14  xyz -71.036785  15.289568
15  xyz 65.246215   49.247986
16  xyz -29.249612  1.043781
17  xyz -25.848495  11.490416
18  xyz -11.223688  NaN
```

expected result for this KEY_COLUMN: `-36.8273304`

Comment: It looks like you want an average, so why not using `mean` instead of `sum` after aggregating?

Comment: The R code is correct. i need it as it is translated to python @Learningisamess

Comment: @Bernouy can we see a sample df and the expected result?

Comment: @Chris i did a edit

Comment: @Bernouy what calculations are you doing to get `-12.5461...` i am not familiar with r

Comment: Thats what i ask...i am not familiar with r as well.... the given R code calculates the result `-12.5461644` for the given example DF.

Comment: @Chris sorry i posted a wrong example DF and wrong result. Now it should be correct.

Comment: In the python code the `/ table['ground_dist']` looks odd. In the R code it divides by the sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK now your expected result makes sense now

First create a function that uses np.sum() this is the equivalent of R's sum(value, na.rm = T)

```
def my_agg(df):
    names = {
        'result': np.sum(df['track_wind_component'] * df['ground_dist']) / np.sum(df['ground_dist'])
    }

    return pd.Series(names, index=['result'])

df.groupby('KEY_COLUMN').apply(my_agg)
```

out:

```
            result
KEY_COLUMN  
xyz        -36.827331
```

What was wrong with your code:

```
table['temp'] = (table['track_wind_component'] * table['ground_dist']) / table['ground_dist']

# this is just creating a column that is the exact same as
# table['track_wind_component'] because, for example, (x*y)/y = x

AVERAGE_WIND_COMPONENT = table.groupby(['KEY_COLUMN'])['temp'].sum()

# you are now essentially just grouping and summing the track_wind_column
```

what the R code is doing is taking the sum of `(table['track_wind_component'] * table['ground_dist'])` divided by the sum of `(table['ground_dist'])`

all which is grouped by the key_column

The R code is also ignoring NaN values that is why I used `np.sum()`

Comment: There is something wrong when i run your code...i get `2.373595` as result..for every KEY_COLUMN the same result

Comment: @Bernouy let me double check

Comment: @Bernouy I am unable to reproduce that issue.